# SQL Server 2008 - Same query, same server instance, multiple databases with same tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 1 SQL server 2008 instance with multiple identical databases.
I wish to run the same query (for example: add column to a table) on all the databases.
I wish to use an array which include databases names.

How can I do this in SQL Server?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run SQL across multiple databases by just using the syntax [dbname].[schema].[tablename]

So you can easily write dynamic SQL to INSERT INTO [dbname].[dbo].[TableName] whatever you want.

You can even write one SQL query that joins tables from two different databases using this syntax.

In your case, just build the SQL statement up in a string, and then call EXEC to execute it.  You can declare a table variable at the top and insert the names of the databases into it, and use that in your SQL Query to build the SQL string.  Or query sys.databases with an appropriate WHERE clause to get the DB names.  Then use those values to build and execute the appropriate SQL for each database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you recommend on a book/site to learn the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the databases by querying sys.databases and then use a dynamic sql statement in a cursor over the query with the select statement suitably qualified by the current value ie, database name.

Here is a sample script that will output the results for my databases with names that end with 'commerce'. It would be trivial to modify this to insert into a temp table instead of select

```
DECLARE DBS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT name
    FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE name like '%Commerce'

DECLARE @DB SYSNAME

OPEN DBS

FETCH NEXT FROM DBS INTO @DB

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 1 DB_NAME(), * FROM ' + @DB + '.dbo.dbversion ORDER BY ExecutionDate desc'
    exec(  @sql )

    FETCH NEXT FROM DBS INTO @DB
END

CLOSE  DBS
DEALLOCATE DBS
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. How can I add my databases names in "WHERE name like '%Commerce'" part ?

Comment: the cursor is just a simple select statement so you could use a simple comma separated list where name in ('a', 'b', 'c')

Answer (score 0):

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command

it is undocumented, and the command will need to check which database it is working on to exclude the ones you don't want